# Rails 4 access table attributes from has_one association

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-one

i have two models User and account where

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account
end

 class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :User
    end
```

in my users controller i am retrieving the users by

```
@user = User.list('', false,'company', 'asc')
```

where the "list" is a method described in my model to retrieve the records

in the users table i have two columns "id" and "company_name"
and in the account table i have the columns as "user_id" and "country"

now i want the array @user to retrieve the company name and their country which can be found by user_id in accounts table

please tell me how can i do this
thankx in advance

Comment: How the output data that you want should look ?

Comment: that when i write User.each do|f|
f.company_name
f.country
end
so there should be company name with their country

Comment: Do you want to loop your @user array only or I can offer another solution how to  retrieve users ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :account

  scope :with_account_info, -> { includes(:account) }
  default_scope{with_account_info}
end
```

The final two lines could be merged into one if you prefer that, i.e.:

```
default_scope{ includes(:account) }
```

HTH

Comment: will the query remain same ?

Comment: @Anatoly Some times debugging with default_scope is night mare.. :) Better is use named scope.

Comment: @Anatoly yes, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

In your controller

```
@users = User.joins(:account)
```

The in your view

```
@users.each do |user|
  user.company_name
  user.account.country
end
```